# T-Sql how do you filter by case

Tags: t-sql

How do you filter by case?

```
select * from address
where streetnum > 1000 only when state = MI otherwise select everything else
```

or

```
select * from address
where case when state = MI then streetnum > 1000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I interpret your question correctly then...

```
select * from address 
where state <> 'MI' or (state = 'MI' and streetnum > 1000)
```

Answer (score 2):

Get all rows from `address` but when `state` is `'MI'` then `streetnum` has to be greater than `1000`.

```
select * from address
where streetnum > 1000 or state <> 'MI'
```

If you want to use a `case` you probably have more than one value to check against.

```
select *
from address
where case state
       when 'MI' then 1000
       when 'MA' then 1000
      else 0
      end < streetnum
```

And that would be the same as this if you have the same value (1000) for all states.

```
select * 
from address
where streetnum > 1000 or state not in ('MI', 'MA')
```